# Product Qty update after order place Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product, orders, event-observer, cataloginventory

I am doing it via observer but nothing is working. here is my code snippet:
**config.xml**

```
   <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
        <observers>
            <qtyupdate>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>qtyupdate/observer</class>
                <method>SetBackToInStock</method>
            </blogapi>
        </observers>
    </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
```

I have tried with sales_order_place_after as well, but nothing is working with that, so using checkout_onepage_controller_success_action event.

**Observer.php               //  First Way**

```
public function SetBackToInStock(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $productIds = array();
        $qty = 1;      

        if ($order) {
            foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
                if(trim(($product->getCondition())) == '812')
                {
                    $productIds[] = $item->getProductId();
                }
            }
        }
        if (!empty($productIds)) {
            foreach ($productIds as $idx => $id) {
                $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
                $productId = $_product->getId();
                $_product->getStockItem()
                    ->setData('qty', $qty)
                    ->setData('is_in_stock', 1)
                    ->save();
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

**Second Way**

```
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($productId);
            $stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 1);
            $stockItem->setData('qty', $qty);
            $stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 1);
            $stockItem->save();
```

**Third Way**

```
 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
            Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->backItemQty($id, $qty);
```

I want to update qty and inventory status of product after order success. None of the above code in observer working for me.

I print the log it enters in the function.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do ?? Why are you forcefully setting the qty to 1 ? Please explain the case scenario. Thanks

Comment: @AbdulPathan, We always have 1 qty for machines (products) but now for some machines we want that admin will set out of stock. So Set it 1 again after order success.

Comment: Why dont you simply set Manage Stock to `No` for the products which will always have Qty as 1 & always In Stock??

Comment: But we are using product inventory status on many places like custom reports, It is still give us the inventory status to in stock ?

Comment: @AbdulPathan, Can you let me know what is wrong in above code, why nothing is working?